# How to match a hover button effect using css animations?

Tags: css

Im trying to replicate a button hover effect into a preloader.

With the button on hover the blue goes from left to right and then when you come off the white comes in from the left and finish on the right.

That's ideally what I'm trying to replicate, see the codepen link below:

Button [Codepen](https://codepen.io/MrJoshFisher/pen/xxxVOom?editors=1100)

```
/* HTML */
<a href="#" class="btnslide"><span class="text">View Our Projects</span></a>

/* CSS */
    .btnslide {
font-family:'futura-pt';
font-size:14px;
background-color:#fff;
color:#2A4173;
border:2px solid #2A4173;
display:inline-block;
padding:10px 45px;
text-decoration:none;
text-align:center;
position:relative;
margin-bottom:1em;
outline:none;
-webkit-appearance:none;
border-radius:0
}    

.btnslide img {
max-height:10px;
margin-left:5px
}    

.btnslide img.white {
display:none
}    

.btnslide:hover img.blue {
display:none
}    

.btnslide:hover img.white {
display:inline-block
}    

.btnslide:before {
background-color:#2A4173;
content:"";
color:#fff!important;
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
-webkit-transform:scaleX(0);
-ms-transform:scaleX(0);
transform:scaleX(0);
-webkit-transform-origin:right;
-ms-transform-origin:right;
transform-origin:right;
-webkit-transition:-webkit-transform .4s cubic-bezier(.19,1,.22,1);
transition:-webkit-transform .4s cubic-bezier(.19,1,.22,1);
-o-transition:transform .4s cubic-bezier(.19,1,.22,1);
transition:transform .4s cubic-bezier(.19,1,.22,1);
transition:transform .4s cubic-bezier(.19,1,.22,1),-webkit-transform .4s cubic-bezier(.19,1,.22,1);
will-change:transform
}    

.btnslide:hover:before {
-webkit-transform:scaleX(1);
-ms-transform:scaleX(1);
transform:scaleX(1);
-webkit-transform-origin:left;
-ms-transform-origin:left;
transform-origin:left
}    

.btnslide:hover span.text {
color:#fff
}    

.btnslide span.text {
-webkit-transition:color .4s cubic-bezier(.19,1,.22,1);
-o-transition:color .4s cubic-bezier(.19,1,.22,1);
transition:color .4s cubic-bezier(.19,1,.22,1);
position:relative;
z-index:2
}    

.btnslide span.text span.plus {
font-size:25px;
line-height:0;
position:relative;
top:3px
}
```

Ive almost got it working the blue comes in and then the white comes in but then it shows white coming in a bit from the right which i'm trying to stop.

Preloader [Codepen](https://codepen.io/MrJoshFisher/pen/eYYBgJO?editors=1100)

```
 /* HTML */
 <a href="#" class="btnslide"><span class="text">View Our Projects</span></a>

/* CSS */
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}    

.btnslide {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 14px;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #2A4173;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}
.btnslide span.text {
  -webkit-transition: color 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
  -o-transition: color 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
  transition: color 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  display: block;
}
.btnslide span.text img {
  max-height: 150px;
}
.btnslide:before {
  background-color: #2A4173;
  content: "";
  color: #fff !important;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  -ms-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: right;
  -ms-transform-origin: right;
  transform-origin: right;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 5s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
  transition: -webkit-transform 5s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
  -o-transition: transform 5s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
  transition: transform 5s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
  transition: transform 5s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1), -webkit-transform 5s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
  will-change: transform;
  -webkit-animation: fontbulger 5s infinite;
  /* Safari 4+ */
  -moz-animation: fontbulger 5s infinite;
  /* Fx 5+ */
  -o-animation: fontbulger 5s infinite;
  /* Opera 12+ */
  animation: fontbulger 5s infinite;
}
@keyframes fontbulger {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
    -ms-transform: scaleX(0);
    transform: scaleX(0);
    -webkit-transform-origin: left;
    -ms-transform-origin: left;
    transform-origin: left;
  }
  30% {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
    -ms-transform: scaleX(1);
    transform: scaleX(1);
    -webkit-transform-origin: left;
    -ms-transform-origin: left;
    transform-origin: left;
  }
  60% {
    -webkit-transform-origin: right;
    -ms-transform-origin: right;
    transform-origin: right;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: unset;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
    -ms-transform: scaleX(0);
    transform: scaleX(0);
    -webkit-transform-origin: right;
    -ms-transform-origin: right;
    transform-origin: right;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: unset;
  }
}
.btnslide:hover:before {
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  -ms-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
  -webkit-transform-origin: left;
  -ms-transform-origin: left;
  transform-origin: left;
}
```

Im not sure if there is a more simple way to achieve this, but I would really appreciate any help that anyone has to offer.

Thanks Again

Comment: The issue is that any easier way to do this would not work the way you want, since using CSS transitions for this is not really an option (they would reverse and you would want a different effect when you leave the hover but CSS has no way to know this).

Comment: Yeh thought it would be too complex to achieve using animations, either that or I just have a giant fixed width div that's blue to go across the screen.

Comment: manage to crack it with a really big div behind - https://codepen.io/MrJoshFisher/pen/YzzpNbv